# Meteor methods bug. Object being unset after collection update

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

I'm having a very strange bug(?) when updating multiple collections in one Meteor method.

I set an object containing the method's arguments, and then push it to arrays in three different collections. The first time I do this, it works, but then after the object is an empty object. It seems very odd behavior!

The method is only called once, and whichever order I collections in, the same happens.

```
myMethod(_id, _cId, _uId, _log, _time) {
    console.log('method called'); // only logs once

    let _obj = {
        id : _id,
        log : _log,
        time : _time,
        user : _uId
    };

    console.log(_obj); // the object as expected

    Site.CollectionOne.update(_id, {$push : {"logs" : _obj }});

    console.log(_reaction, _id, _cId, _uId, _log, _time); // {} "theID" "theCID" "theUID" "the log message" 1234567890. The object has been emptied.

    Site.CollectionTwo.update(_cId, {$push : {"logs" : _obj }});
    Meteor.users.update(_uId, {$push : {"logs" : _obj }});
},
```

The logs are the same on the client and on the server.

Comment: What happens if you `Site.CollectionOne.update(_id, {$push : {"logs" : _.extend({}, _obj) }});`?

Comment: that's fixed it... but still seems odd! Any idea why it behaves this way?

Comment: If you pass an object as opposed to a literal to a JS function, it gets passed by reference rather than value.  So if `update` does anything to the object you pass it (as it appears to), you see those changes in the calling function as it's actually the same object.  By using `_.extend` (or `Object.assign`) like this, you create a copy of the object to pass into the function, so it doesn't matter if that gets mutated.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to put this as an answer than I'll upvote / accept it.

Comment: Done, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an object as opposed to a literal to a JS function, it gets passed by reference rather than value. So if `update` does anything to the object you pass it (as it appears to), you also see those changes in the calling function as it's actually the same object that's being changed.

By using _.extend (or Object.assign), you can create a copy of the object to pass into the function, so that it doesn't matter if that gets mutated.  For example:

```
Site.CollectionOne.update(_id, {$push : {"logs" : _.extend({}, _obj) }});
```